# Redirection on AWS, when using ALB + Cognito + ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to setup a backend, which is composed of several microservices. They use Fargate for provisioning. The Tasks run in a private subnet, which are connected to an application load balancer (ALB) in a public subnet. The target group associated with the ALB points to the cluster. Nothing special until here and everything works fine.

However, I want to offload authentication to AWS Cognito. I added a user pool, an app client and so on. I can log me in with my test user, but afterwards is receive an `401 Authorization Required`. I want to use `code grant` from OAuth2. Is this even possible with an ALB or do I need an API Gateway? And if it's possible how do I set the callback url's in my app client?
After successful authorization cognito should redirect (with callback url's) to the ECS service, which is exposed by the ALB DNS. However, then again the ALB would first try to authenticate, which is the first rule in the ALB. I think I miss-configured the callback url's or do I have to create additional path in my backend?

At the moment I have these callback url's:

- `https://<alb_address>.<zone>.elb.amazonaws.com/oauth2/idpresponse`
- `https://<app_client_address>.auth.<zone>.amazoncognito.com/idpresponse`
- `https://<app_client_address>.auth.<zone>.amazoncognito.com/ouath2/idpresponse`

To summarize I want to create this architecture

`ALB --> TargetGroup --> AWS Cognito (code grant) -->  ECS`

Comment: Is [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/built-in-authentication-in-alb/) an option for you?

Comment: @amitd sounds very interesting. I will have look into it :)

Comment: To which path did you configure cognito authentication in ALB listener rules?